# want to schedule a job in windows slave for android project by using gradle as build tool

Tags: android, windows, jenkins, gradle, build.gradle

In my Jenkins environment Linux as master and windows as slave. I want to build a job in windows slave machine for android project. I have installed android sdk and git and java and downloaded gradle in windows slave machine. How we can configure a build job and where we can provide that gradle path and android sdk path?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Gradle Wrapper with your Gradle project, then you never need to install Gradle anywhere, as the Gradle wrapper bootstraps the Gradle distribution automatically.

Comment: Thanks @vampire, could you know where can we provide andriod studio path??